# Getting the right type/encoding from a java HTTP response

Tags: java, http, inputstream, outputstream

I am using the `java.net.*` libraries and need help getting the right type/encoding back from the server. To clarify, I know my server-side program returns the double value of `0.0` and when I do:

```
OutputStream output = httpConn.getOutputStream()
output.write(query.getBytes(charset))              //where query contains the URL arguments and charset is UTF-8
InputStream response = httpConn.getInputstream();
response.read();
```

I get the integer value `48` which I know is the ASCII value of 0. What can I do to always ensure that I get a value of type `Double?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStream.read()` returns the next byte that comes from the stream. `Double` value types are 64-bits long (8 bytes).

Maybe you need `DataInputStream`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

```
InputStream response = new DataInputStream(httpConn.getInputstream());
double result = response.readDouble();
```